# How do you download a Xbox 360 games to a PC via a usb cable?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, fallout-new-vegas

I have Fallout: New Vegas for my Xbox 360 and would like to transfer it to my desktop

Comment: I highly doubt this is possible in any legal sort of way, but then again hte world has surprised me before.

Comment: Most games have completely different versions for Xbox and for PC.  I'm not certain whether F:NV is one of those games, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: While the game will most likely not work on a pc, I suspect there are other reasons as to why you want to do this. I myself have no idea how to do it but I can bet it is definitely possible. Maybe not through a usb but some other device. If you are trying to transfer from a physical disk then it would be even easier to burn it from that to a regular blu-ray or cd disk. Whichever would have more space.

Answer (score 10):

You can't do this.

The Xbox 360 version of the game is a different piece of software to the PC version so even if you did manage to copy or read the disk on a PC, you'd need to somehow emulate a 360 (not really possible for AAA games yet, at least not without a monstrous PC).

If you want to play Fallout on your PC, you'll have to buy the PC version.